# Map a request DTO property to a URI parameter of a different name in ServiceStack without using DataMember?

Tags: c#-4.0, rest, servicestack, dto

Based on the example from ServiceStack's wiki, if you have a URI like this:

```
www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/servicestack/hello?Name=World
```

Your request DTO would look like this:

```
[Route("/hello")]
public class Hello
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However if the URI is like this:

```
www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/servicestack/hello?n=World
```

How would you use the same DTO above but have Name mapped to "n"? Is there an attribute you can decorate DTO properties with that would do this?

I tried using the DataContract and DataMember attributes like so:

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/hello")]
public class Hello
{
    [DataMember(Name = "n")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine however, when you have a lot of properties it stops working unless you decorate every property with [DataMember] attribute.

Is there anyway to provide the custom name of the param that differs from the property without using DataContract and DataMember? Maybe a custom attribute provided by ServiceStack so only the ones that need to be mapped differently have attributes and the rest are left alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way for .NET DataContract Serializers to use a different name on your DTO is to use `[DataMember]` attribute. If you don't want to do that, you can make the property name the same name as the QueryString variable (which is case-insensitive).

Other than that you provide your own [Custom Request Binder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization) or you can access the QueryString directly from inside your service or filters with:

```
var name = base.Request.QueryString["n"];
```

If you're doing this a lot for a lot of variables you can wrap extracting from QueryString and populating the request DTO into a [Filter Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes)

Comment: SO you are saying there is currently no way to do it other than using DataMember.  You should know of course :). It seems a little overkill to decorate every member with a empty DataMember attribute just so you can have one that specifies the name like so DataMember(Name =" n").  But so be it. Thanks for confirming.